# Extract data in Checkbox region

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, omr

I want to extract the data after the checkbox.

[image]

For example in the image for checkbox there is tickmark for `NO` we want to extract `NO`. are there any OMR tools or any computer vision algorithms for this.